# How to make menu animation play after game has loaded or fix animation not playing after scene change

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have an animation in the main menu scene(text and buttons coming from the side of the screen into their places) that works fine when the game opens and starts in the menu scene, but if the player goes to another scene and then returns to the menu the animation does not play, I fixed that by making the animator for the menu in upscaled time and now works fine no matter the scene the player comes from, but now my problem is that if I open the game for the first time, the animation plays before the game has loaded( I think ) so I see only the result of the animation (text and buttons in their places), if I go in any other scene and then back on the menu the animation works fine, the upscaled time fixed on problem and created another but it's only the very FIRST time you open the game, I can fix that by removing the upscaled time but then the first problem comes back, any ideas what I can do?
Thank you kindly!

Answer (score 1):

You're problem is that your animation is playing on Awake. Awake happens once the scene is loaded, whether or not the user has gotten there themselves.

Go into your animator. Right click and press create new empty state. Right click on that state and click "Set as default state" This state should remain empty.

Create a new script and call it whatever you want.
Add this:

```
public Animator anim; // drag in the animator that you are having issues with.
private void Start()
{
    anim.Play("NameOfIntroAnimation");
}
```

The reason this will work is because Start() is run on the first frame, not the Awakening of the scene.